# Add Disk to filesystem mounted on disk?

Tags: linux, lvm

Was tasked by client to expand this pivotal filesystem to avoid another outage. However, I see the filesystem is mounted on a local disk:

```
df-     
/dev/sdd 591G 358G 204G 64% /opt/....

fstab     
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c65ef238-d8ae-49a4-9be6-a45872052d2f /opt/... auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I see a local disk that is available:

```
lsblk     
sdb 8:16 0 600G 0 disk
```

I've never added a raw disk to a filesystem mounted on a disk, usually via vg. Anyway to expand this filesystem with the available disk?

Hoping the filesystem was listed within a vg and could easily expand with free disk in flight.

Comment: Do we talk about virtual machine or physical server?

Comment: Iit's not possible to extend a physical partition. You're very much missing the LVM layer (this isn't true if you use btrfs or zfs for /opt, as they bring their own volume management). So, I'm afraid that live extension won't be possible. For how long would you be allowed to stop whatever things are accessing /opt? What's the file system on /dev/sdd?

Comment: this is a physical machine

Comment: I figured it wasn't possible to expand a physical disk. I've reached out to the client with alternatives. Thank you for the help!